# Waterproofing Roof Fan Flange

Tags: roof, waterproofing

I installed this turbine exhaust vent on my 1/12 (almost flat) roof.

[image]

As per the instruction, I used roofing nails to attach the bottom half of the flange while the top half is tucked under the roofing material (modified bitumen).

Do I need to waterproof these nails? If yes, can I just use roofing cement or should I use roofing patch tape (brand "Eternabond") like this:

[image]

Or is it better to use patching material like I had a professional apply for some repairs while ago with a propane torch, which looks like this:

[image]

or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the low-slope, I would seal all around that flange rather than just dabbing roof tar on the nail heads. You are just one plugged scupper away from a bad rainy day...

Torch-down is great if you can get a small piece to cut up for this small job. Maybe beg a piece off a roofer you know or at a roofing job in your hood.

Elastomeric patching and coating compounds work good too, use a reinforcing fabric/mesh.